# Replacing built-in types with more complex types. Python

Tags: python

I want to create a replacement class of the built-in type `set` that can be constructed exactly like set. Inheritance must not be used because some functions are removed to trigger `method not found` exceptions. This class is also used to find places where there might be implicit type conversions of the built-in python collection types.

```
class SetFacade:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.lst = list(iterable)

    # other allowed member functions...
```

The problem with this constructor definition is, that I cant call the constructor `SetFacade()` without arguments.

How can I create a constructor that behaves exactly like the built-in set?

Thus it must allow

- `SetFacade([a,c,b])`
- `SetFacade([])`
- `SetFacade()`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not using hash builtin"?

Comment: Note that you should at least be inheriting from object.

Comment: @larsmans I don't want set to implicly call `element.__hash__()` on my elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have an empty constructor...

```
class SetFacade:

def __init__(self, iterable=None):
    if iterable is None: 
         iterable = []
    self.lst = list(iterable)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't think about default arguments to get overloaded functions. A bit of a no brainer though I need to admit.

Comment: I edited the code, as it included one of the most subtle and hard to find cause of errors in Python programs - if the list is used as the method's default argument, it is created only once -- all instances of your class would share the same list object with the original code.

Answer (score 4):

Define *exactly*...

The best way to create a set-like class is to derive from [`collections.Set`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes). You'll need to implement `__len__`, `__iter__` and `__contains__`.

To be able to add element, derive from `collections.MutableSet` instead and implement `add` and `discard`.

Answer (score 2):

Inherit from `set`:

```
>>> class SetFacade(set):
...     pass
...
>>> SetFacade([1,2,3,4])
SetFacade([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> SetFacade([1,2,3,3])
SetFacade([1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: the point of all this is to overwrite *all* functions of set, because many of them rely on hashing.

Comment: @Alex 'all' != 'many'.  Consider customizing __hash__ methods of planned set elements instead of customizing whole set class.

Comment: I want for instance certain operators disabled. it's not about the exact behaviour of the class -- Just of the constructor. It's to find badly written code, that may trigger implicit conversions.

Comment: @Alex: "It's to find badly written code, that may trigger implicit conversions".  Please actually say that in the question.  Don't hide important facts in comments.

Comment: @S.Lott: I refined the question, even though I had the answer already. Generally I agree here, but the comment above was offtopic because it's not about constructors.